# How do I get all y-values on scale line in Chart.js?

Tags: angular, ionic2, chart.js, chart.js2

We have a line chart that has weights for the y-values. This could be something like [184, 182, 179, 180, 178, 178, 175]. We want to be able to get the y-values on the line that are between those numbers. So for instance, if someone's mouse is sitting somewhere between 182 and 179 on the x-axis, we want to be able to get the y-value of the line associated with that x-value.

Is this possible?

P.S.  We're using the ng2-charts wrapper of Chart.js 2, with Angular 2 and Ionic 2. Thanks.